# PHP - How to conditionally merge some keys of an array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array of an array. I need to modify it in such a way that only if `company` and `type` of an array is same as any of its sibling array, then their `cars` array gets merged. Consider the following array:

```
array(
    array(
        'company' => 'Jeep',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'    => array(
            'Compass',
        ), 
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Jeep',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'    => array(
            'Wrangler',
        ), 
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Mercedes',
        'type'    => 'Sedan',
        'cars'     => array(
            'C-Class',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Mercedes',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'     => array(
            'G Wagon',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Jeep',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'    => array(
            'Cherokee',
        ), 
    ),
)
```

Expected output after proccesing the above array should be:

```
array(
    array(
        'company' => 'Jeep',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'    => array(
            'Compass',
            'Wrangler',
            'Cherokee',
        ), 
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Mercedes',
        'type'    => 'Sedan',
        'car'     => array(
            'C-Class',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Mercedes',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'car'     => array(
            'G Wagon',
        ),
    ),
)
```

I have tried foreach loop but I can't figure it out. I think it could be done with recursion but I don't from where should I start.

```
    foreach ( $array as $one ) {
        foreach ( $array as $two ) {
            $zzz = [];
            if ( $one['company'] === $two['company'] && $one['type'] === $two['type'] ) {
                if ( $one['cars'] === $two['cars'] ) {
                    $zzz = $one;
                } else {
                    $zzz = [
                        'company'    => $one['company'],
                        'type' => $one['type'],
                        'cars'     => array_merge( $one['cars'], $two['cars'] ),
                    ];
                }
            } else {
                $zzz = $one;
            }
            $temp[] = $zzz;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simple loop with if condition. Good luck.

Comment: What is your logic?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have added my code. It doesn't work. That's I didn't add it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those simple things that look like they're hard to wrap your head around:

```
$input = array( /* ... your original array ... */ );
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $icar)
{
    $filed = false;
    foreach ($output as $okey => $ocar) // look for existing brand and type to file into
        if ($ocar['company'] == $icar['company'] && $ocar['type'] == $icar['type'])
        {
            $output[$okey]['cars'][] = $icar['cars'][0];
            $filed = true;
            break; // no need to continue once we put it somewhere
        }

    if (!$filed) // it's a new brand and type so we copy the entire thing
        $output[] = $icar;
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: I am not a down-voter but question with no code effort need to be closed not answer

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm sorry for not adding code when I posted my question. I edited and added it later on.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse your array by the loop and check condition whether company and type is already set or not

```
$arr  =array(
    array(
        'company' => 'Jeep',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'    => array(
            'Compass',
        ), 
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Jeep',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'    => array(
            'Wrangler',
        ), 
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Mercedes',
        'type'    => 'Sedan',
        'cars'     => array(
            'C-Class',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Mercedes',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'     => array(
            'G Wagon',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'company' => 'Jeep',
        'type'    => 'SUV',
        'cars'    => array(
            'Cherokee',
        ), 
    ),
);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($arr as  $value) {
  if(isset($new_array[$value['company']."_".$value['type']]))
    $new_array[$value['company']."_".$value['type']]['cars'][]=$value['cars'][0];
  else
    $new_array[$value['company']."_".$value['type']]=$value;  
}
$new_array = array_values($new_array);
var_dump($new_array);
```